# Beamer \visible slide transitions, caption does not work

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, captions, transition

I have the MWE with "visible" transitions; there are elements that are visible in <1> and elements that are visible in <2>.

I obtain the desired result until I try to mess with captions; the moment I try to add the caption of Figure B in <2> (commented in the MWE), I get the like one million errors, starting with:

> Improper \spacefactor. \end{frame}

NOTE THAT I WANT TO ADD DIFFERENT CAPTIONS FOR FIGURES A AND B.

This is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\usepackage[labelformat=empty,font=scriptsize,skip=0pt,
justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{figure}
    \begin{measuredfigure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, every node/.style={inner sep=0,outer sep=0,align=left}]
    \node (node1) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=6.8cm]{example-image}};

    \visible<1>{
        \node[right=6.9cm of node1.south west, anchor=south west] (node2) {\includegraphics[width=3.75cm]{example-image-a}};
    }
    \visible<2>{
        \node[right=6.9cm of node1.south west, anchor=south west] (node2) {\includegraphics[width=3.75cm]{example-image-b}};
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \visible<1>{
        \captionof{figure}{\hspace{6.9cm}caption of figure A}
    }
    %\visible<2>{%WORKS UNTIL I TRY TO ADD THIS CAPTION
    %   \captionof{figure}{\hspace{6.9cm}caption of figure B}
    %}
    \end{measuredfigure}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Which produces:

[image: A]

[image: B]

Note the absence of caption under B... How can I make it work?? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**
try the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance =0mm and 5mm,
    every node/.style={anchor=west, align=center}
                    ]
\node (a) {\includegraphics[width=6.8cm]{example-image}};
\visible<1>{
\node (b) [above right=of a.south east] {\includegraphics[width=3.75cm]{example-image-a}};
\node[below=of b] {caption of figure A};
            }
\visible<2>{
\node (b) [above right=of a.south east] {\includegraphics[width=3.75cm]{example-image-b}};
\node[below=of b] {caption of figure B};
            }
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

In case of multi line caption is sensible define separate style for nodes with caption. For example:

```
 capt/.style = {text width=#1, align=left}
```

and than instead `\node[below=of b] {caption of figure B};` use

```
\node[capt=3.75cm, below=of b] {caption of figure B};
```

Comment: This is not what I am looking for, the caption of figure B should be different from the caption of figure A...

Comment: I see there might be a confusion with the names I gave to the nodes, let me clarify the MWE

Comment: Yes that's what I thought... as in my other question, we need another node for captions in these scenarios, we cannot just use captionof{figure}